# Is there a spinor category?

Tags: category-theory, physics, mathematical-physics, spin-geometry

I am just wondering how do spinors relate to category theory?

- Can a category of spinors be defined? If so how?
- Can the spinor space be defined by universal property (w.r.t a vector space) in the same way that the tensor algebra can be?